# What is the usage of biometrics(Touch ID/Face ID) API that cannot identify multiple users?

Tags: ios, biometrics

[Question]

I understand biometrics API(Touch ID/Face ID) is for authenticating if the birometrics are registered to the device and not for identifying multiple users.

I think this behavior is reasonable because biometrics information is very sensitive information.

My question is "But then what is the usage of biometrics API?"

If the device is unlocked from the beginning and somebody except the device's owner can run the app that requires Touch ID/Face ID authentication, he also can register his fingerprint or face to the device and pass the authentication.

My understanding for the usage of biometrics API is for the trivial privacy protection when your family or friend ask you lend your iPhone temporally to google searching or call someone.

Please tell me if I'm misunderstanding something.

[Information I already tried]

I installed 1Password and asked my coworker to register his face to my iPhone X(iOS 12.1.2), He also can access my credentials through iOS's auto-filling function.

Comment: Touch ID/Face ID - its single user authentication , if you want to register the new user you need to deregister the before logged

Comment: the passcode is mandatory before registered

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.I will cancel my question.

Add face ID requires Passcode and I forgot that I did input Passcode before asking my coworker to register his face.

Comment: welcome bro....